# mac os x authorization plugin through bluetooth

Tags: macos, authentication, authorization, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is it possible create authorization plugin for login screen with BLE support? (not lock screen)

Can BLE start in the preLogin mode ?

for example add BLE to this example
https://github.com/skycocker/NameAndPassword

Thanks